# textfield + scrollview weird issue ios7

Tags: uiscrollview, ios7, tableview, xcode5

I have tableview and textfield in negative frame as it is shown in screenshot now when i start to edit **text table's scrollview goes down by 20 or 50 pixel**.

[image]

[image]

the same thing is working fine in iOS6. It's also calling scrollview's delegate method. I cant figure it out.

Help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in viewDidLoad or loadView method,

```
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = FALSE;
}
```

In iOS 7, the scrollview layout is adjusted as per the translucent property of the navigation bar. It might be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to autolayout. Really if you wanna check then just a second uncheck your autolayout option in your xib and then check. I'm sure i won't go 20 or 50 pixel down.

**Solution :**
Make vertical difference 0 between tableview and text filed. After that it won't go 20 or 50 pixel down.